# Table has no column named tkinter sqlite

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter

i'm trying to add 'componente' to my sql column 'componenti' in the table but, when i try to do it,i get this error:"table (table_name) has no column named (column_name)".
I think i used the correct sintax so i can't figure out why.
Im sure that the database name, which i connected to, is right.
Thanks in advance.
Heres the part of code i'm talking about.

```
#it's sql lite btw
def inserisciDati():
    global tabellaNuova
    #immagazzinare il valore di ogni componente
    valuesComponenti = list(componente.get() for componente in contentComponenti)
    #immagazzinare il prezzo di ogni componente
    valuesPrezzi = (prezzo.get() for prezzo in contentPrezzi)
    #connettersi al database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Clienti.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    tabellaNuova = str(inputNome.get())
    nomiTabelle.append(tabellaNuova)
    #crea tabella sql
    c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """ + tabellaNuova + """(
            componenti VARCHAR(50)
        );
    """)
    #inserire componenti nella nuova tabella
    for componente in valuesComponenti:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO " + tabellaNuova + " VALUES ('" + componente + "');")
```

Comment: Why don't you print the value of : tabellaNuova  first, ?

Comment: The error is not related to the name of the table, it is *column not found* error.  However the INSERT SQL statement does not specify any column name, so I wonder why you got such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the table column that you are inserting into from what I can tell.

```
#inserire componenti nella nuova tabella
    for componente in valuesComponenti:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO " + tabellaNuova + "(componenti) VALUES ('" + componente + "');")
```

Comment: It is valid not to specify the column if the number of values is the same as the number of columns in the table.